# Equivalence of category of internal groups and the category of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, model-theory

Is the category of internal groups in set equivalent to the category of groups or isomorphic to it or are they just equal?

When we define an internal group in Set since the product is unique only up to isomorphism we will have internal groups that are not in the traditional form of a group. For example, you would have an internal group whose domain of multiplication is {0,1,2,3} and whose underlying set is {0,1}. However, every internal group would be equivalent to an ordinary group. And therefore the category of internal groups in Set would be equivalent to the category of groups.

If what I have written is true then there are internal groups that are not groups in the traditional sense. So why everywhere you see the definition of internal group as a first example it is said that an internal group in Set is just a group? Do they have this isomorphism in mind?

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Your argument about the domain of multiplication is equally applicable to the traditional definition of a group, unless you insist on fixing in advance a particular construction of the cartesian product.  So the question has nothing to do with the concept of an internal group, but rather the difference between different constructions of cartesian products of sets.  Of course, they are all naturally isomorphic as functors.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: And also, we do not really care whether two category are equal or isomorphic. For all practical purpose, even if they were merely equivalent, one would still feel entitled to say that a group internal to set is the same thing as a group.

Comment: @SimonHenry Dear Professor Henry. I know, but I just wanted to make sure that I have understood the concept. I would very much like to hear your opinion. I know that equivalence means just the same when we are talking about categories. What I am trying to ask is that whether my reasoning is sound or not. Am I missing something or do we get the category of groups up to equivalence? I came across a theorem in elephant (Johnstone, cor. D1.2.14) which says that the category of internal models of a geometric theory is equivalent to the category of models of that theory. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @amirhomayounNejah : sorry, I didn't meant to imply that you are wrong, justs that when people say "group object in sets are the same as ordinary group" they don't neccessarily mean that the category are equal or even isomorphic, a mere equivalence is enough. And whether the category are going to be equal, isomorphic or equivalent mostly depends on techincal details in the definition. (I can give you three different definition of "group object" that are all reasonable and would lead to respectively "equivalent", "isomorphic" or "equal" categories of groups. )

Comment: @SimonHenry Dear Professor Henry. I really appreciate your answer. Thank you so much, sir. Thank you for your time and effort.